# how can i separate between two arrays inside a parent array

Tags: julia

this code is a small example of what i want to do, i have this small example right here:

```
y=[[[1,0],[0,0],[1,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]],[[1,0],[0,0],[1,1],[0,0]],[[1,0],[0,0],[1,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]]
array=[]
all_array=[]
for i in 1:length(y)
    for j in 1: length(y[i])
        if y[i][j]==[1,0]
            push!(array,y[i][j])
        end
        
    end
end
```

what i'm expecting  when you return `array` is this :

```
[[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]],[[1,0]],[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]]
```

which is `3-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}`
but instead i get this:

```
8-element Array{Any,1}:
 [1, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [1, 0]
```

i don't know what i'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing all the elements that satisfy your condition one after another in `array`. You could create your array instead like:

```
julia> array=[[],[],[]]
```

And modify your loop to `push!` into each subarray `array[i]` like this:

```
julia> for i in 1:length(y)
           for j in 1: length(y[i])
               if y[i][j]==[1,0]
                   push!(array[i],y[i][j])
               end

           end
       end
```

Which then gives you your desired array.

```
julia> array
3-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
 [[1, 0]]
 [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
```